# Is it possible to write a WebExtension in WebAssembly?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions, webassembly

I wonder if it is possible to use WebAssembly to develop an add-on for Firefox.

I doubt that it is possible to do completely in WASM, but what about WASM core with minimal JavaScript wrapper?

Comment: I don't see why not. Why don't you try it? You could start from this tutorial: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Your_first_WebExtension

Comment: it would be interesting to do it with Kotlin. It can work as JS or as WebAssembly with the same Kotlin code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there are already WebExtensions using wasm, e.g. see the [release notes for uBlock Origin 1.17.4](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/releases/tag/1.17.4).

Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/a4072a/can_i_use_wasm_in_webextensions/